# Man pages for standard C and C++ libraries on Fedora 14

Tags: fedora, package-management, man, c

How do I install them? At present, `man fopen` gives me `No manual entry for fopen`. I have the compilers installed and have verified that things do build without problems.

**Update:** This is what I got when I tried the suggested solutions on Fedora 14:

```
[root@damien agnel]# yum install man-pages libstdc++-docs
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Adding en_US to language list
Setting up Install Process
Package man-pages-3.25-1.fc14.noarch already installed and latest version
Package libstdc++-docs-4.5.1-4.fc14.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
[root@damien agnel]# man std::iostream
No manual entry for std::iostream
[root@damien agnel]#
```

Comment: yum install man-pages

Comment: @penguin: That should be an answer, not a comment.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Man pages for the standard C library are included in the `man-pages` package. For the C++ STL library the man-pages and HTML documentation are included in the `libstdc++-docs` packages. Thus,

```
yum install man-pages libstdc++-docs
```

should install them. You can test if they are available via:

```
man std::iostream
man fopen
```

Kind of off-topic: IMHO the libstdc++ documentation (especially the man pages) is not that convenient to browse - I usually use http://en.cppreference.com/w/ which is very convenient to navigate and up-to-date - either I use the integrated search feature or I use google search like 'c++ reference iostream' and the first hit usually points to a cppreference.com page anyways. It is also available as [offline copy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Cppreference%3aArchives).

**Edit:** Tested `man std::iostream` on a FC 14 box with `libstdc++-docs` installed, and surprisingly, it could not find it.

Using `yum povides '*/std::iostream*'` prints that the `libstdc++-docs` package *provides* the corresponding man-page file, but it installs it to an unusual location:

```
/usr/share/man/man3/man3/std::iostream.3.gz
```

Thus, calling `man` like

```
man -M /usr/share/man/man3 std::iostream
```

shows the man-page.

Looks like a bug in the FC 14 `libstdc++-docs` package to me.

Comment: Could you also mention how to find that information for one's self? [I though `yum provides fopen.3`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12691) would indicate which package contains the `fopen` man page, but apparently that's wrong. What's the Fedora (yum) equivalent of Debian's (apt's) `apt-file search fopen.3`?

Comment: The equivalent is `yum provides '*/fopen.3*'` - without globing it does not search filenames.

Comment: it doesn't seem to work. installation looks like it is successful but "man std::iostream" still fails to return docs.

Comment: @Agnel Kurian, check out my last edit.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
yum install man-pages
```

Comment: Thanks, using this command the C library docs were installed. But I am still unable to find man pages for iostream and friends.

Answer (score 0):

`yum provides '*/fopen.3*'` will tell you what package is available that contains a file called `fopen.3*` (i.e. the `fopen` man page). *(thanks [maxschlepzig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/1131/maxschlepzig))*

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work either: "No Matches found".